# adding array objects for button

Tags: iphone

I have two arrays vowels and alphabetImages consists with images and place random images,

```
while ([randomset count]<2)
{
    [randomset addObject:[vowels objectAtIndex:rand()%5]];
}
while ([randomset count]<7)
{
    [randomset addObject:[alphabetsImages objectAtIndex:rand()%25]];
}
final = [randomset allObjects];
finalMutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:final];
for (UIButton *btn in arrayButtons)
{
    //[btn setImage:final forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

what is need is,
In arrayButtons i have 7 buttons and want to place those randomly picked images in that,how to do this.
Any help is appreciated,Thanks in advance

Comment: You cant do using fast enumeration. for conventional for loop.

Comment: then how i can i get those images on btns

Comment: images are in array, pick one image from array store it in UIImage, then use `setImage:`

Comment: In finalmutable i donot have images, i have values then how i can get those images from that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ([randomset count]<2)
{
    [randomset addObject:[vowels objectAtIndex:rand()%5]];
}
while ([randomset count]<7)
{
    [randomset addObject:[alphabetsImages objectAtIndex:rand()%25]];
}
final = [randomset allObjects];
finalMutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:final];

[arrayButtons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *btn, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [btn setImage:[final objectAtIndex:idx] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }];
```

Enumarate the `arrayButtons` using the `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` block to get the id of the buttons in array.